# issues passing a boolean as a constructor parameter

Tags: java, swing, boolean

first I ask the user whether or not it wants to be the first to make a move on a game or if not the computer will play first by doing the following:

```
boolean playFirst = !gameName.equals("GUESSING GAME")
            && JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to play "
            + "FIRST?")
            == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
```

then I want to pass that answer to the game(s) constructor.

Nim:

```
public Nim(boolean playSmart, boolean playersTurn)
{
    this.playSmart = playSmart;
    this.playersTurn = playersTurn;
    this.gameRecord = "THE GAME OF NIM";

    Random generator = new Random();

    this.pileSize = generator.nextInt( 91 ) + 10;        
}
```

Tic Tac Toe:

```
public TicTacToe(boolean playSmart, boolean playersTurn)
{
    this.playSmart = playSmart;
    this.playersTurn = playersTurn;
    this.gameRecord = "TIC-TAC-TOE";

}
```

the game(s) only work properly when the player selects to play first but if they want to play second the player goes first as well.

I tried to run the program with random boolean values in the constructor

```
this.itsMyTurn = ( new Random() ).nextBoolean();
```

and when I do this the program works perfectly, but it doesn't work the way I want it to work by getting the answer from the user and then pass in it to the constructor.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Are those constructors complete? Otherwise I'd make the wild guess that you're mixing the local variable `playersTurn` and the field `playersTurn` in some place.

Comment: I'm assuming this returns true? `!gameName.equals("GUESSING GAME")`

Comment: Those are the only areas of the constructors where I update those variables besides from after each player makes a move the variable is set to the other player.

Comment: superEb: That would return true only when the player selects to go first as well I thought... I have 3 games and two of them take the parameters while GUESSING GAME doesn't.

Comment: You should explicitly println the result of `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to play "
            + "FIRST?")
            == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION`. I don't think the trouble is with writing the value to the object.

Comment: This is also suspect: you have both `playersTurn` and `itsMyTurn` variables? Your program logic may be off, then: setting one variable, but cheking the other when it's time to decide which player goes.

Comment: Marko Topolnik: you are right the only value passed is "true" for whatever reason. Thanks for helping me spot the problem. isMyTurn its only used on the GUESSING GAME and playersTurn on the other two game constructors.

Comment: we need more code to see the error. So far looks ok.

Comment: I found the error. It was with the way I stored the boolean expression from the user which was storing true always...